# Install Ubuntu on empty hard drive

Tags: system-installation

Can I install Ubuntu on an empty hard drive? Or do I need Windows installed to install it?

Comment: most of the true dedicated linux enthusiasts actually install only linux on their hard disk and try to do everything with that only.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  You can install Ubuntu on a fresh drive, Along side Windows, and other ways.  Form DVD, and USB.  For information on how to install Ubuntu see [Install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid installing Ubuntu on your external hard drive using a USB or DVD. If you install Ubuntu on your external hard drive while booting from USB or DVD, you will need to connect your external hard drive to your computer every time you want to use it.
Instead use VMware Player to install Ubuntu on external hard drive.

Comment: First of all, where do you see a reference to *external* hard drive? Secondly, I don't think you can install OS on external USB drive.

Comment: 1. He didn't specify internal or external hard drive. So i just wanted to caution him. 

2. I have installed Ubuntu on my external hard drives number of times. I am 100% sure that it can be done.

Since you have a very high reputation, I'll remove my answer if you think that I am wrong. But please do try it out once for yourself.

Comment: 1. Because it's obvious. 2. Ok, partially agree. But not all BIOS are supporting that. Sure, you can keep your answer, however, I do not think it's valid within this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will be able to install on a blank hard drive.  The installer will just have you partiton you hard drive.